# powershell find iis virtual application name from url

Tags: powershell, iis, web-administration

I have a url, i want to find the application name on which the url is binded.
the command `get-website -name "url"`  return nothing as the url name is binded to the Virtual directory.
the command `get-webbinding -name "url"` return  the binding but not the Name of the application.

Which powershell command can I use to find IIS virtual application name from url?

Comment: SO Rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What did you search for? This is a very common thing to do. There are many samples ( and Youtube videos) all over the web showing how to do this. ['powershel get web application from url'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershel+get+web+application+from+url%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Comment: What do you mean by IIS virtual application name?